# Error:Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'

Tags: angular

After executing ng Serve command getting this error.Here is the details of my application:-

### Package                           Version

@angular-devkit/architect         `0.10.7`
@angular-devkit/build-angular     `0.901.1`
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   `0.901.1`
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     `0.901.1`
@angular-devkit/core              `7.0.7`
@angular-devkit/schematics        `7.0.7`
@angular/cli                      `7.0.7`
@angular/compiler-cli             `9.1.2`
@ngtools/webpack                  `9.1.1`
@schematics/angular               `7.0.7`
@schematics/update                `0.10.7`
rxjs                              `6.3.3`
typescript                        `3.1.6`
webpack                           `4.42.0`

Comment: Hi, please paste whole error message into your question. You could also add code you believe is directly related to this error

Comment: Just added the whole error msg Kindly check once .Thanks in advance!!